# Constructed dynamically Sql with checking table for data presence

Tags: oracle, dynamic-sql

I am trying to convert such SQL to Oracle which is constructed dynamically and executed with Sql Server:

```
DECLARE @dynamicQuery varchar(8000)
DECLARE @criteriaMet BIT

SET @dynamicQuery = ''
IF @criteriaMet = 1
BEGIN
  SET @dynamicQuery = 'IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM DATATABLE) '
END
SET @dynamicQuery = @dynamicQuery + 'INSERT INTO DATATABLE (...) VALUES (...)'

EXEC @dynamicQuery
```

But with Oracle I cannot use EXISTS in IF statement and have to declare variables and select count into the variable, but doing that inside dynamic SQL drastically reduces readability and increases complexity. Is there more elegant way of doing building dynamic SQL which checks for table data presence in Oracle based on some criteria?

Comment: Why does it need to be dynamic SQL? You only seem to have static SQL. You can't put the count and logic in PL/SQL, and make insert static too?

Comment: DATATABLE is a variable used in a cursor

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't need to be dynamic, so you can do a static count, logic to check the count, and then a static insert if suitable:

```
declare
  cnt pls_integer;
begin
  select count(*)
  into cnt
  from dual
  where exists (select null from your_table);

  if cnt = 0 then
    insert into your_table (id, foo) values (1, 'bar');
  end if;
end;
/
```

You don't need PL/SQL at all though, you can do `insert ... select ...` and make the `exists` check part of that:

```
insert into your_table (id, foo)
select 1, 'bar'
from dual
where not exists (select null from your_table);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e83f89a9ce334c7e42de0d3acfee43db)

Either can be converted to be dynamic if there is actually a reason to do that, such as a run-time table name; the second option is probably still going to be more readable - the first would a dynamic query followed by the logic to do a dynamic insert.

---

> I am trying to attach additional check to existing Merge statement only if some criteria is met, so it is less changes to the original

You could change `TBL2` to a subquery, which apply the conditions you want; when those aren't met there is nothing for the merge to match. Something like:

```
'MERGE INTO' || TBL || ' USING ( SELECT * FROM ' || TBL2 ||
' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM ' || TBL || ')' ||
' )' ON (' || COLS || ' ) WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ( ' || COLS || ' VALUES (' || COLS || ')'
```

... where the middle line

```
' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM ' || TBL || ')' ||
```

can apply whatever conditions you want.

Comment: So you don't want to insert anything if the target table isn't empty, not just when the `on` isn't met? Why merge in that case, as that condition will always be true if the table is empty?

Comment: Exactly, using this statement in a cursor with different table names. that's why I need dynamic SQL. Insert used here for simplicity, but actual sql constructed is 
`MERGE INTO' || TBL || ' USING ' || TBL2 || ' ON (' || COLS || ' ) WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ( ' || COLS || ' VALUES (' || COLS || ')'`.
I am trying to attach additional check to existing Merge statement only if some criteria is met, so it is less changes to the original

Comment: There are tables that needs to be merged with always, and there are tables that needs to be merged with theirt counterparts only if they are empty. During script execution I don't know which tables are empty, and which tables already have data. So if table is empty I add sample data, otherwise this means user already has data and he needs no sample data in the table or the sample data was removed earlier, so user does not get sample data twice.

Comment: Thank you, Alex, for the update. Created final statement using your suggested variant
`USING ( SELECT * FROM ' || TBL2 || TMPSQL || ') '` where TMPSQL depends on criteria `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM ' || TBL || ')' or sometimes an empty string ''